# How to get the positions of the k greatest(or smallest) elements of a vector?

Tags: r

I have a vector and I want to find the indices of the k greatest elements, not the elements themselves which I could do with sort. One idea would be to add indices to the values and have a custom sort function that only compares the first elements of pairs (a classical solution to this problem) but surely there has to be a simpler way ? Note that performance isn`t a matter.

Comment: I do not get why my question was closed, the linked answer only finds the values, not positions, of the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I create a random vector:

```
vector <- c(1, 3, 6, 2, 7, 8, 10, 4)
```

Next, you can use the following code which will output the top `k` elements as `x` with index `ix`:

```
k <- 3

lst <- sort(vector, index.return=TRUE, decreasing=TRUE)
lapply(lst, `[`, lst$x %in% head(unique(lst$x),k))
```

Output:

```
$x
[1] 10  8  7

$ix
[1] 7 6 5
```

As you can see `ix` gives the index of the top `k` elements.

Comment: I see, I didn´t know sort has this index return feature. But could you please elaborate on the purpose of lapply ? What is this bracket for `[` ?

Comment: @eternalstudent, it returns the output as a list to make sure you see which values are the top elements with a certain index. The `[` is just to subset the dataset based on the index returned from the top elements. Check for more info on `?"["`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `rank`.

```
x <- c(1, 3, 6, 2, 7, 8, 10, 4)

seq_along(x)[rank(-x) < 4]
# [1] 5 6 7
```

If you have ties, the result is this:

```
x <- c(10, 3, 6, 2, 7, 8, 10, 4)

seq_along(x)[rank(-x) < 4]
# [1] 1 6 7
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I selected the other one since it came before, but this answers a slightly different problem : In case of ties your solution doesn´t give the positions of the k greatest elements, but maybe less (in your example it´s the positions of the 2 greatest elements instead of 3). Nevertheless it´s interresting to see both approaches.